# Ubuntu 14.04 launcher transparency doesn't work, possible driver issue

Tags: 14.04, unity, drivers, launcher, transparency

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I noticed that the launcher had no transparency, so I looked up the problem and found that Unity Tweak Tool could help. However, this was no use at all, no matter what I set the transparency to, the launcher didn't go any transparent at all.

[image: Picture showing how there is no transparency in the launcher]

I believe the problem is to do with the drivers, because when I tried switching from the X.Org to the proprietary driver, the transparency started working, however I've had to switch back the the open source X.Org driver, because the proprietary fglrx driver had VERY bad performance issues, with even opening a window up lagging.

[image: Picture showing additional drivers]

Is there any way to fix the transparency issue on the open source drivers?
I am using Radeon HD 6670 by the way.

EDIT: Transparency at other places doesn't work either, for example at notifications or that pop-up you get when you want to shut the computer down, where you can choose to restart or shut the computer down.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading from 14.04 LTS to the currently newest 15.10. This solved my problem, now everything's working fine.